# Defining roles and permissions for office 365 users and groups

Tags: cloud, office365, orchestration, azure-ad-graph-api

I am working on a cloud-orchestration application where I wish to provide access to office 365 resources to my organization's users. The user selects the 'office 365' icon shown in UI and asks for permission to access the set of office 65 resources. The admin would provide access for all or some of the office 365 resources.I have analyzed Microsoft's Graph API to create/update/delete users and groups.

Consider the example that I have bought 50 office 365 licences and provide access to the users for specific resources like share point, excel etc.,

I am unable to find-out the office 365 API's to create roles and permission for roles and then to apply roles to users.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to assign the different licences to the users via the Microsoft Graph? If I understand correctly, you can assign the licences using the rest below(refer to [here](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_assignlicense)):

```
POST /users/<id | userPrincipalName>/assignLicense
```

> > I am unable to find-out the office 3656 API's to create roles and permission for roles and then to apply roles to users.

Would you mind share more detail about the permission/roles you want? For example, how you assign them manually?

Comment: License can have access to multiple applications of office365. For example, I have a licence which provide access to 4 different office365 applications, but I wish to provide permission for user1 to access 2 of them and user2 to access rest of them.